# Hide specific variant image from catalog gallery but display on click in Shopify?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, shopify

This is my shopify catalog product page: https://example.com/products/dummy-product
I want to hide variant images from catalog gallery but want to display if user on click to any variant see the screenshots of my catalog: https://prnt.sc/RcPz4IxA48mb, https://prnt.sc/Ng_1FY6aRxGH

When user click on specific variant then I want to display the variant image on change see the screenshots: https://prnt.sc/3XH6_truwSZZ, https://prnt.sc/ARJPv3hrUXoJ

I have tried via css `.product__thumbs--scroller .product__thumb-item:nth-child(2) {display: none; }, .product__thumbs--scroller .product__thumb-item:nth-child(3) {display: none;}` then it will hide this from catalog gallery see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/2swbfp9cSJ-T and the problem is I have more catalog products how can I hide them from all because every product have different number of catalog image slides.

Pleas help.

Comment: Can you please provide html as well as css that you have written so we got clear idea about same.

Comment: @PatelHarsh, hi mate look at this website: https://levanzaherbals.com/products/tar-clean-lungs-detox-syrup-lungs-cleaner-for-smokers-ayuvedic-syrup-for-detoxification, all the variant images hide from product gallery section but display once you click on the variant of the product. I need the that exactly in my store. But how please help.

Comment: Could you please help me dear @PatelHarsh